# OPA matcher for sap.ui.commons.MessageBox

Tags: sapui5

How can I to catch a messagebox?

I tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```
iShouldSeeConfirmPopup: function(sTitle) {
    return this.waitFor({
        controlType: "sap.ui.commons.MessageBox",
        matchers: function(oControl) {
            return oControl.getTitle() === sTitle;
        },
        success: function(oControls) {
            ok(true, "I see a confirm popup");
        },
        errorMessage: "Did not find confirmation popup"

    });
}
```

I took a look on API of MessageBox [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.html). But, I think it doesn't support `getTitle()`

Please teach me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.waitFor({
    pollingInterval : 100,
    viewName : "sap.ui.commons.MessageBox",
    check : function () {
        return !!sap.ui.test.Opa5.getJQuery()(".MessageBox").length;
    },
    success : function () {
        ok(true, "I see a confirm popup");
    },
    errorMessage : "Did not find confirmation popup"

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the UI is built by another guy without class. So, I cannot use this way. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "sap.ui.commons.Dialog" as the controlType for your matcher

The commons MessageBox is appears to be an instance of a commons Dialog,
 see https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/commons/MessageBox.html using UI5 console plugin